# Attaching a SQL server express database with WCF service application

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2008, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I am writing a WCF service application and my front end that is consuming is winforms.

I am trying to connect to SQL Express in WCF as database, the issue i face is the connection string, i have a database created under app folder in WCF project,

This is my connection string in wcf project:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;
AttachDbFilename=\\App_Data\\Database1.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

I get this error,

> SqlException was unhandled by user code
>
> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   \App_Data\Database1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists,
>   or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

How do i attach a SQL Server Express database in a WCF service application project (with appropriate connection string) so that the consuming application can view the data from this DB? Any help will be highly helpful? Thanks.

Comment: Is the Database1.mdf file read only or do you know if another process is locking that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code for the SqlConnection

```
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;User Instance=true");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this site:

1. [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)
2. [Connecting to sql server database mdf file without installing sql server on client machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054905/connecting-to-sql-server-database-mdf-file-without-installing-sql-server-on-clie)

and try this connectionstring also:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;
Initial Catalog=Database1;
Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```