# SQL Connection String for another pc

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I developed an application. It loads sql database on my pc with this connection string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Database\Books.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Database\Books.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Lessons", con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        grdPersonnel1.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];
        con.Open();
    }
```

but, my Database data doesn't load in another pc!

Comment: Does the other computer have this file?  `D:\Database\Books.mdf`

Comment: _What error do you get?_

Comment: My datagrid doesn't load data from database.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: No, other PCs are not nework.

Comment: I used this page http://www.connectionstrings.com/ but, i can't find best way.

Comment: Please give us more information about _what happens_ when you try to load the database. Is there an error? What is it?

Comment: There is not any error, as i said when my dataGrid load in another pc, can not read database data and all cells of dataGrid are null.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SQL server instance Running on that Computer?

Try to Run your Application/Solution on the other P.C on Debug Mode you will see what exactly is the error...make sure you have try and catch in each of  your methods/ events.

check this SO post :

[Is it possible to run a mdf database without SQL Server program? (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366586/is-it-possible-to-run-a-mdf-database-without-sql-server-program-c)

[Connecting to sql server database mdf file without installing sql server on client machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054905/connecting-to-sql-server-database-mdf-file-without-installing-sql-server-on-clie)

Regards

Comment: Yes, SQl server 2008 is run on target pc.